# How to get the xml data in the form of array using php

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

I want to get the values of the XML below, which has time sheet details like `XConsultant`, `personid`, `TimeSheet.WeekEnd` , `TimeRecord.WeekEnd` and so on. I  had tried  with:

```
$fileData = simplexml_load_file($fileName);//where file name is the destination of my file url ..
```

When I am trying to load and print the array, it's only printing the timesheet details. I want to access the `personid` and `[TimeSheet].[WeekEnd]`

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [weekdayStart] => Monday
        )

    [0] => 10/29/2018
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [weekdayEnd] => Sunday
        )

    [0] => 11/04/2018
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [weekdayStatement] => Wednesday
        )

    [0] => 11/07/2018
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [weekdayLastRun] => Saturday
        )

    [0] => 10/29/2018
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 11/07/2018 00:51:43
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [XConsultant] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 27189
                )

            [ClientXrefNbr1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [PersonID] => 24799
            [PersonCode] => DHinkle12345
            [Email] => test1@gmail.com
            [FirstName] => David
            [MiddleInitial] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LastName] => hennry
            [VendorXRefNbr1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [VendorXRefNbr2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
        )

    [TimeSheet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [WeekEnd] => 10/28/2018
                    [WeekBegin] => 10/22/2018
                )

            [ApprovalHistory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Activity] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [status] => SUBMITTED
                                            [datetime] => 10/26/2018  7:30PM
                                            [person] => David hennry
                                            [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                            [comment] => 
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [status] => COMPLETED
                                            [datetime] => 10/29/2018 11:56AM
                                            [person] => David hennry
                                            [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                            [comment] => 
                                        )
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [status] => LOCKED
                                            [datetime] => 11/01/2018  5:05AM
                                            [person] => David hennry
                                            [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                            [comment] => Locked By System [4667]
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )

            [TimeRecord] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8.0000
                    [1] => 8.0000
                    [2] => 8.0000
                    [3] => 8.0000
                    [4] => 8.0000
                )
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [XConsultant] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32971
                )

            [ClientXrefNbr1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [PersonID] => 30305
            [PersonCode] => mailk123
            [Email] => test2@yahoo.com
            [FirstName] => mailk
            [MiddleInitial] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LastName] => tom
            [VendorXRefNbr1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [VendorXRefNbr2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [TimeSheet] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [WeekEnd] => 10/28/2018
                            [WeekBegin] => 10/22/2018
                        )

                    [ApprovalHistory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Activity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [status] => SUBMITTED
                                                    [datetime] => 10/27/2018 10:45AM
                                                    [person] => mailk tom
                                                    [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                                    [comment] => 
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [status] => COMPLETED
                                                    [datetime] => 10/30/2018 12:20PM
                                                    [person] => mailk tom
                                                    [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                                    [comment] => 
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [status] => LOCKED
                                                    [datetime] => 11/01/2018  5:05AM
                                                    [person] => mailk tom
                                                    [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                                    [comment] => Locked By System [4667]
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [TimeRecord] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8.0000
                            [1] => 8.0000
                            [2] => 8.0000
                            [3] => 8.0000
                        )
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [WeekEnd] => 11/04/2018
                            [WeekBegin] => 10/29/2018
                        )

                    [ApprovalHistory] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Activity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [status] => SUBMITTED
                                                    [datetime] => 11/02/2018  7:46PM
                                                    [person] => mailk tom
                                                    [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                                    [comment] => 
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [status] => COMPLETED
                                                    [datetime] => 11/05/2018 11:01AM
                                                    [person] => mailk tom
                                                    [role] => TimeSheetUser
                                                    [comment] => 
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [TimeRecord] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8.0000
                            [1] => 8.0000
                            [2] => 8.0000
                            [3] => 7.7500
                            [4] => 8.0000
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I used `foreach` and associative array key condition also, but I am unable to fetch the records. Where is `<ConsultantTime>`? I have many consult time data where I need to have `foreach` loop `</ConsultantTime>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<TimeSheets><TimePeriod><Start weekdayStart="Monday" xmlns="">10/29/2018</Start><End weekdayEnd="Sunday" xmlns="">11/04/2018</End><StatementDate weekdayStatement="Wednesday" xmlns="">11/07/2018</StatementDate><LastRunDate weekdayLastRun="Saturday" xmlns="">12/28/2018</LastRunDate><SystemDate xmlns="">11/07/2018 00:51:43</SystemDate></TimePeriod><Client organization="abc">abc</Client><Supplier organization="fsdf, Inc." name="fsdf, Inc.">fsdf, Inc.

<ConsultantTime>
<XConsultant id="27189"><ClientXrefNbr1></ClientXrefNbr1><PersonID>24799</PersonID><PersonCode>DHinkle12345</PersonCode><Email>test1@gmail.com</Email><FirstName>David</FirstName><MiddleInitial></MiddleInitial><LastName>hennry</LastName><VendorXRefNbr1></VendorXRefNbr1><VendorXRefNbr2></VendorXRefNbr2></XConsultant>
<TimeSheet WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018">
<ApprovalHistory><Activity status="SUBMITTED" datetime="10/26/2018  7:30PM" person="David hennry" role="TimeSheetUser" comment="" /><Activity status="COMPLETED" datetime="10/29/2018 11:56AM" person="David hennry" role="TimeSheetUser" comment="" /><Activity status="LOCKED" datetime="11/01/2018  5:05AM" person="David hennry" role="TimeSheetUser" comment="Locked By System [4667]" /></ApprovalHistory>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018" workdate="10/22/2018" payCode="RT" projectID="Default" projectType="T&amp;M" ProjectCode="N/A" PrjMgrLastName="" PrjMgrFirstName="" PrjMgrEmail="" TimeHeaderKey="361511" TaskID="10323" TaskName="Operating Expense" MSTaskID="Default-Operating Expense" MSProjID="Default" FinTaskNumber="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber1="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber2="" ResourceFinTaskNumber1="" ResourceFinTaskNumber2="" MasterProjectID="0" MasterProjectName="" SOP98="N" TaskWBSCode="60041" TimeSystemCostCenter="4200G" ExpOrgType="" AccruedTime="0" Comments="Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: " ApproverName="" BillToOrganization="BSC" VendorXRefNbr1="" VendorXRefNbr2="" VendorXRefNbr3="" VendorXRefNbr4="" VendorXRefNbr5="" VendorXRefNbr6="" VendorXRefNbr7="" VendorXRefNbr8="" VendorXRefNbr9="" VendorXRefNbr10="">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018" workdate="10/23/2018" payCode="RT" projectID="Default" projectType="T&amp;M" ProjectCode="N/A" PrjMgrLastName="" PrjMgrFirstName="" PrjMgrEmail="" TimeHeaderKey="361511" TaskID="10323" TaskName="Operating Expense" MSTaskID="Default-Operating Expense" MSProjID="Default" FinTaskNumber="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber1="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber2="" ResourceFinTaskNumber1="" ResourceFinTaskNumber2="" MasterProjectID="0" MasterProjectName="" SOP98="N" TaskWBSCode="60041" TimeSystemCostCenter="4200G" ExpOrgType="" AccruedTime="0" Comments="Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: " ApproverName="" BillToOrganization="BSC" VendorXRefNbr1="" VendorXRefNbr2="" VendorXRefNbr3="" VendorXRefNbr4="" VendorXRefNbr5="" VendorXRefNbr6="" VendorXRefNbr7="" VendorXRefNbr8="" VendorXRefNbr9="" VendorXRefNbr10="">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018" workdate="10/24/2018" payCode="RT" projectID="Default" projectType="T&amp;M" ProjectCode="N/A" PrjMgrLastName="" PrjMgrFirstName="" PrjMgrEmail="" TimeHeaderKey="361511" TaskID="10323" TaskName="Operating Expense" MSTaskID="Default-Operating Expense" MSProjID="Default" FinTaskNumber="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber1="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber2="" ResourceFinTaskNumber1="" ResourceFinTaskNumber2="" MasterProjectID="0" MasterProjectName="" SOP98="N" TaskWBSCode="60041" TimeSystemCostCenter="4200G" ExpOrgType="" AccruedTime="0" Comments="Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: " ApproverName="" BillToOrganization="BSC" VendorXRefNbr1="" VendorXRefNbr2="" VendorXRefNbr3="" VendorXRefNbr4="" VendorXRefNbr5="" VendorXRefNbr6="" VendorXRefNbr7="" VendorXRefNbr8="" VendorXRefNbr9="" VendorXRefNbr10="">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018" workdate="10/25/2018" payCode="RT" projectID="Default" projectType="T&amp;M" ProjectCode="N/A" PrjMgrLastName="" PrjMgrFirstName="" PrjMgrEmail="" TimeHeaderKey="361511" TaskID="10323" TaskName="Operating Expense" MSTaskID="Default-Operating Expense" MSProjID="Default" FinTaskNumber="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber1="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber2="" ResourceFinTaskNumber1="" ResourceFinTaskNumber2="" MasterProjectID="0" MasterProjectName="" SOP98="N" TaskWBSCode="60041" TimeSystemCostCenter="4200G" ExpOrgType="" AccruedTime="0" Comments="Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: " ApproverName="" BillToOrganization="BSC" VendorXRefNbr1="" VendorXRefNbr2="" VendorXRefNbr3="" VendorXRefNbr4="" VendorXRefNbr5="" VendorXRefNbr6="" VendorXRefNbr7="" VendorXRefNbr8="" VendorXRefNbr9="" VendorXRefNbr10="">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd="10/28/2018" WeekBegin="10/22/2018" workdate="10/26/2018" payCode="RT" projectID="Default" projectType="T&amp;M" ProjectCode="N/A" PrjMgrLastName="" PrjMgrFirstName="" PrjMgrEmail="" TimeHeaderKey="361511" TaskID="10323" TaskName="Operating Expense" MSTaskID="Default-Operating Expense" MSProjID="Default" FinTaskNumber="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber1="Default" ProjectFinTaskNumber2="" ResourceFinTaskNumber1="" ResourceFinTaskNumber2="" MasterProjectID="0" MasterProjectName="" SOP98="N" TaskWBSCode="60041" TimeSystemCostCenter="4200G" ExpOrgType="" AccruedTime="0" Comments="Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: " ApproverName="" BillToOrganization="BSC" VendorXRefNbr1="" VendorXRefNbr2="" VendorXRefNbr3="" VendorXRefNbr4="" VendorXRefNbr5="" VendorXRefNbr6="" VendorXRefNbr7="" VendorXRefNbr8="" VendorXRefNbr9="" VendorXRefNbr10="">8.0000</TimeRecord>
</TimeSheet>
</ConsultantTime>

</Supplier></TimeSheets>
```

Answer (score -2):

This code here will parse the XML in `$input`. Substitute `$input` for whatever variable currently holds your XML

```
<?php
$input = "<TimeSheets><TimePeriod><Start weekdayStart=\"Monday\" xmlns=\"\">10/29/2018</Start><End weekdayEnd=\"Sunday\" xmlns=\"\">11/04/2018</End><StatementDate weekdayStatement=\"Wednesday\" xmlns=\"\">11/07/2018</StatementDate><LastRunDate weekdayLastRun=\"Saturday\" xmlns=\"\">12/28/2018</LastRunDate><SystemDate xmlns=\"\">11/07/2018 00:51:43</SystemDate></TimePeriod><Client organization=\"abc\">abc</Client><Supplier organization=\"fsdf, Inc.\" name=\"fsdf, Inc.\">fsdf, Inc.
<ConsultantTime>
<XConsultant id=\"27189\"><ClientXrefNbr1></ClientXrefNbr1><PersonID>24799</PersonID> 
<PersonCode>DHinkle12345</PersonCode><Email>test1@gmail.com</Email> 
<FirstName>David</FirstName><MiddleInitial></MiddleInitial> 
<LastName>hennry</LastName><VendorXRefNbr1></VendorXRefNbr1><VendorXRefNbr2> 
</VendorXRefNbr2></XConsultant>
<TimeSheet WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\">
<ApprovalHistory><Activity status=\"SUBMITTED\" datetime=\"10/26/2018  7:30PM\" 
person=\"David hennry\" role=\"TimeSheetUser\" comment=\"\" /><Activity 
status=\"COMPLETED\" datetime=\"10/29/2018 11:56AM\" person=\"David hennry\" 
role=\"TimeSheetUser\" comment=\"\" /><Activity status=\"LOCKED\" 
datetime=\"11/01/2018  5:05AM\" person=\"David hennry\" role=\"TimeSheetUser\" 
comment=\"Locked By System [4667]\" /></ApprovalHistory>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\" workdate=\"10/22/2018\" 
payCode=\"RT\" projectID=\"Default\" projectType=\"T&amp;M\" ProjectCode=\"N/A\" 
PrjMgrLastName=\"\" PrjMgrFirstName=\"\" PrjMgrEmail=\"\" TimeHeaderKey=\"361511\" 
TaskID=\"10323\" TaskName=\"Operating Expense\" MSTaskID=\"Default-Operating 
Expense\" MSProjID=\"Default\" FinTaskNumber=\"Default\" 
ProjectFinTaskNumber1=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber2=\"\" 
ResourceFinTaskNumber1=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber2=\"\" MasterProjectID=\"0\" 
MasterProjectName=\"\" SOP98=\"N\" TaskWBSCode=\"60041\" 
TimeSystemCostCenter=\"4200G\" ExpOrgType=\"\" AccruedTime=\"0\" Comments=\"Time In: 
8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 
12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: \" ApproverName=\"\" 
BillToOrganization=\"BSC\" VendorXRefNbr1=\"\" VendorXRefNbr2=\"\" 
VendorXRefNbr3=\"\" VendorXRefNbr4=\"\" VendorXRefNbr5=\"\" VendorXRefNbr6=\"\" 
VendorXRefNbr7=\"\" VendorXRefNbr8=\"\" VendorXRefNbr9=\"\" 
VendorXRefNbr10=\"\">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\" workdate=\"10/23/2018\" payCode=\"RT\" projectID=\"Default\" projectType=\"T&amp;M\" ProjectCode=\"N/A\" PrjMgrLastName=\"\" PrjMgrFirstName=\"\" PrjMgrEmail=\"\" TimeHeaderKey=\"361511\" TaskID=\"10323\" TaskName=\"Operating Expense\" MSTaskID=\"Default-Operating Expense\" MSProjID=\"Default\" FinTaskNumber=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber1=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber2=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber1=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber2=\"\" MasterProjectID=\"0\" MasterProjectName=\"\" SOP98=\"N\" TaskWBSCode=\"60041\" TimeSystemCostCenter=\"4200G\" ExpOrgType=\"\" AccruedTime=\"0\" Comments=\"Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: \" ApproverName=\"\" BillToOrganization=\"BSC\" VendorXRefNbr1=\"\" VendorXRefNbr2=\"\" VendorXRefNbr3=\"\" VendorXRefNbr4=\"\" VendorXRefNbr5=\"\" VendorXRefNbr6=\"\" VendorXRefNbr7=\"\" VendorXRefNbr8=\"\" VendorXRefNbr9=\"\" VendorXRefNbr10=\"\">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\" workdate=\"10/24/2018\" payCode=\"RT\" projectID=\"Default\" projectType=\"T&amp;M\" ProjectCode=\"N/A\" PrjMgrLastName=\"\" PrjMgrFirstName=\"\" PrjMgrEmail=\"\" TimeHeaderKey=\"361511\" TaskID=\"10323\" TaskName=\"Operating Expense\" MSTaskID=\"Default-Operating Expense\" MSProjID=\"Default\" FinTaskNumber=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber1=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber2=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber1=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber2=\"\" MasterProjectID=\"0\" MasterProjectName=\"\" SOP98=\"N\" TaskWBSCode=\"60041\" TimeSystemCostCenter=\"4200G\" ExpOrgType=\"\" AccruedTime=\"0\" Comments=\"Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: \" ApproverName=\"\" BillToOrganization=\"BSC\" VendorXRefNbr1=\"\" VendorXRefNbr2=\"\" VendorXRefNbr3=\"\" VendorXRefNbr4=\"\" VendorXRefNbr5=\"\" VendorXRefNbr6=\"\" VendorXRefNbr7=\"\" VendorXRefNbr8=\"\" VendorXRefNbr9=\"\" VendorXRefNbr10=\"\">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\" workdate=\"10/25/2018\" payCode=\"RT\" projectID=\"Default\" projectType=\"T&amp;M\" ProjectCode=\"N/A\" PrjMgrLastName=\"\" PrjMgrFirstName=\"\" PrjMgrEmail=\"\" TimeHeaderKey=\"361511\" TaskID=\"10323\" TaskName=\"Operating Expense\" MSTaskID=\"Default-Operating Expense\" MSProjID=\"Default\" FinTaskNumber=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber1=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber2=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber1=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber2=\"\" MasterProjectID=\"0\" MasterProjectName=\"\" SOP98=\"N\" TaskWBSCode=\"60041\" TimeSystemCostCenter=\"4200G\" ExpOrgType=\"\" AccruedTime=\"0\" Comments=\"Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: \" ApproverName=\"\" BillToOrganization=\"BSC\" VendorXRefNbr1=\"\" VendorXRefNbr2=\"\" VendorXRefNbr3=\"\" VendorXRefNbr4=\"\" VendorXRefNbr5=\"\" VendorXRefNbr6=\"\" VendorXRefNbr7=\"\" VendorXRefNbr8=\"\" VendorXRefNbr9=\"\" VendorXRefNbr10=\"\">8.0000</TimeRecord>
<TimeRecord WeekEnd=\"10/28/2018\" WeekBegin=\"10/22/2018\" workdate=\"10/26/2018\" payCode=\"RT\" projectID=\"Default\" projectType=\"T&amp;M\" ProjectCode=\"N/A\" PrjMgrLastName=\"\" PrjMgrFirstName=\"\" PrjMgrEmail=\"\" TimeHeaderKey=\"361511\" TaskID=\"10323\" TaskName=\"Operating Expense\" MSTaskID=\"Default-Operating Expense\" MSProjID=\"Default\" FinTaskNumber=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber1=\"Default\" ProjectFinTaskNumber2=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber1=\"\" ResourceFinTaskNumber2=\"\" MasterProjectID=\"0\" MasterProjectName=\"\" SOP98=\"N\" TaskWBSCode=\"60041\" TimeSystemCostCenter=\"4200G\" ExpOrgType=\"\" AccruedTime=\"0\" Comments=\"Time In: 8:00 AM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 12:00 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: &#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;Time In: 12:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Time Out: 4:30 PM&#xD;&#xA;Comments: \" ApproverName=\"\" BillToOrganization=\"BSC\" VendorXRefNbr1=\"\" VendorXRefNbr2=\"\" VendorXRefNbr3=\"\" VendorXRefNbr4=\"\" VendorXRefNbr5=\"\" VendorXRefNbr6=\"\" VendorXRefNbr7=\"\" VendorXRefNbr8=\"\" VendorXRefNbr9=\"\" VendorXRefNbr10=\"\">8.0000</TimeRecord>
</TimeSheet>
</ConsultantTime>";

//Create an XML parser object
$p = xml_parser_create();

//An array to put the data into
$data = array();

//Parse the XML into the data array
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $input, $data);

//Show the data array
echo "<pre>" . print_r( $data, 1 ) . "</pre>";
```

Running that code will give you the XML in a structured array, you will be able to process it in a for loop.

Comment: `xml_parse_into_struct` is not so much an XML parser, as a low-level bit of code that might be useful for building an XML parser; the array it produces is unlikely to be useful for, well, anything really. PHP has several *much more user-friendly* ways of working with XML, such as SimpleXML, which the OP already found.